# How to tell is a damaged iPad Air is repairable

Tags: ipad, screen

I was given an iPad Air (model A1474) which seems to had a tough life. The screen and LCD matrix are broken and I would like to know if it is still alive before replacing these broken parts.

How should I proceed? I connected the iPad to a PC with iTunes via USB connection but got no response.

Is there any other way to tell if the iPad is salvageable and can be repaired?

Comment: Feel free to edit this to explain precisely why the linked question doesn't fit your situation. (And your situation is grim if iTunes doesn't recognize a broken device since the window of opportunity for another backup might be closed now.